# I want to add new column in the firestore database depending on how many beds available inputted

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(roomName ?? "").add({
  "roomname": _roomname.text,
  "bedsAvailable": _bedsAvailable.text,
  "price": _price.text,
}).then((value) => Navigator.push(
    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OwnersMain())))
    .catchError((error) => print("something is wrong. $error"));
```

I just wanna add beds in the the column, but in depends on how many bedsAvailable added. Can anybody helps me.. Please.

[image: This is the thing I want to happen]

Answer (score 1):

To generate a list of `Column`'s dynamically, you can use `List.generate()`:

```dart
final bedsAvailable = 5;

final beds = List.generate(
  bedsAvailable,
  (index) => Column(
    children: [
      Text('Bed $index'),

    ],
  ),
);
```

---

Or: you can use a for loop:

```dart
final _beds = [
  for (var i = 0; i < bedsAvailable; i++)
    Text(
      'Bed $i',
    ),
];
```

Note: if `bedsAvailable` in your example is a `String`, you'll have to convert it to an `int`:

```dart
final bedsAvailableInt = int.parse(bedsAvailable);
```